# Proof of triangle inequality (where d is a metric described in the question)

Tags: metric-spaces, correlation, time-series, triangle-inequality

Let $x, y, z$ be some three (real-valued) time series.
Prove that $$\sqrt{1/2-\rho(x,z)/2} \leq \sqrt{1/2-\rho(x,y)/2} + \sqrt{1/2-\rho(y,z)/2}$$

After this assuming that two time series cannot be perfectly correlated if they are not equal it will be possible to show that $d = \sqrt{1/2-\rho/2}$ is indeed a metric.

To be honest, this exercise was given in de Prado's book called "Machine Learning for Asset Managers" as an exercise for a reader, i.e. we know for a fact that $d$ is a metric, however, I am struggling with proving aforementioned triangle inequality. If not the full solution, can one share an idea to solve this without brude forcing correlation formulas into the inequality? I tried that and could not finish till the end.

If that's inevitable, it would help so much if one provided the proof.

With kind regards,
Nura

Comment: Presumably the correlation between the time series.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.3145.pdf should be related to your question. It proves that $d(X,Y) = \sqrt{ 1/2 - \rho(X,Y)/2}$ defines a metric using metric-preserving functions. You should be able to get an explicit proof of the triangle inequality from it.

Comment: Strangely the paper doesn't seem to mention the assumption that perfect correlation holds only for distinct variables (obviously false in general), which indeed should be needed since otherwise $d$ would only define a pseudo-metric, as it does not separate points (as shown here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/521365/correlation-based-distance-dissimilarity-measure-is-not-a-metric)

Comment: Thank you for the paper! It indeed does provide the explanation. However, i just uploaded the course paper I used this in (unfortunately, did not see this earlier) and proved the metric in a different way: 
if one is curious, basically, via z-standartization of x and y, which does not affect correlation coefficient, one can show the linear relationship between euclidean distance of x, y and metric d. If i am not mistaken, it is $||x'-y'|| = 4\sqrt{T}d(x,y).$ T is the number of observations, and $x',y'$ are standartised versions of x,y. So since euclidean distance is indeed a metric, ...